# How can I tint a Texture2D with a gradient?

Tags: c#, directx, lighting, monogame, color

I am working on a lighting system for my game. Instead of lighting each tile completely with only one color, I want to create a gradient on that tile so to make the lighting look more dynamic and nicer.

I am using C# and Monogame (DirectX). Each tile is drawn as a `Texture2D` with this call:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(
    Block.getBlockByID(blockID).getTexture(side),
    new Rectangle(x * 28 - offx, y * 28 - offy, 28, 28),
    color
);
```

The first parameter gets the texture to use and the second one places the texture down. The third one is a pre-calculated `Color` which shades the texture that color. How can I replace that `Color` with a gradient?

Comment: you could probably use a shader for that

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any experience with shaders, all I really do know is that they change the pixels on the screen etc.

Comment: Just use a regular texture that you draw on the whole screen. Have it completely black, and play on the alpha value to have more or less shadow in corresponding areas (0 -> no shadow 1-> pure black). Use linear interpolation to have smooth shadows, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be to create a gradient in Photoshop/Paint.NET/GIMP/whatever you use and blend that with your tile(s).

If you want a more procedural approach, then take a look at `Color.Lerp`. A gradient with that method is simple. The first color parameter is the light shade, the second is the final dark shade and the progress is the row/column of the texture data (depending on vertical/horizontal application of gradient) from 0 to width/height.